# How to allow validation to be skipped in some cases

Tags: java

1. User fills in the form
2. User click on Book button
3. System validates the form
4. When system hits this validation (Quantity Exceed Validation), it will display the common message (Quantity exceeded 100000. Click Book again to continue booking.)
5. User then click on Book button again. **System can then re-validate the form again but skip/ignore the validation (Quantity Exceed Validation).**

Any idea how can this be done?

```
            public String bookAction() {

                // acctcntr required validation
                if (isEmptyNull(_w.getAcctcntr())) {
                    UIComponent c = getIv1102_combo_box_acctcntr();
                    showValidationMessage_ByComponent_Key(c,
                            "iv1102_message_acctcntr_missing");
                    return null;
                }

                // vdate required validation
                if (isEmptyNull(_w.getVdate())) {
                    UIComponent c = getIv1102_input_vdate();
                    showValidationMessage_ByComponent_Key(c,
                            "iv1102_message_missing_vdate");
                    return null;
                }

                // mdate required validation
                if (isEmptyNull(_w.getMdate())) {
                    UIComponent c = getIv1102_input_mdate();
                    showValidationMessage_ByComponent_Key(c,
                            "iv1102_message_missing_mdate");
                    return null;
                }

                // quantity required validation
                if (isEmptyNull(_w.getQuantity())) {
                    UIComponent c = getIv1102_input_quantity();
                    showValidationMessage_ByComponent_Key(c,
                            "iv1102_message_missing_quantity");
                    return null;
                }

                // Quantity Exceed Validation
                if(_w.getQuantity().doubleValue() > 100000){
                    showCommonMessageByKey("iv1102_message_quantity_exceed")
                }

                _w.bookIV();

                return "book_success";
            }
```

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with? You gave us a list of tasks, and some code (without explaining what it refers to). What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: @amit Sorry. I highlighted the part which I am struggling in bold.

Comment: Just add a flag to see whether the validation need to be executed again.

Comment: A boolean value? e.g. `boolean bValidatedOnce = false;`

Comment: YOu need some form of state for the operation. A boolean is fine but you need to store it somewhere relevant, so without seeingyour code, I can only suggest you either add state to the original data model (not always goodd, especially if ir is just for this one case) or if this is a one-off action against the exisiting book, then store the object key and if the very next operation has same key then you know.

Comment: @KDM Could you post your comment as answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a flag to see whether the validation need to be executed again.

```
    if(qExceededValidationRequired && _w.getQuantity().doubleValue() > 100000){
        qExceededValidationRequired = false ; 
        showCommonMessageByKey("iv1102_message_quantity_exceed")
    }
```